# .jar file for postgreSQL JDBC driver. How to configure?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am trying to create a connection for the JDBC driver in netbeans for windows. THe problem is that i cannot make a domain source name with the .jar file provided from `http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html`

Can anyone help?

Comment: I haven't done anything, since i do not know how to work with .jar files. I read somewhere that if i copy the .jar into `TOMCAT_HOME/lib` then it will start working. but i can't find that out. If you know of any binary file for the driver, please post.

Comment: Have you used any jar files in Netbeans before? I just want to understand if the problem is specific to postgre jar or it is just that you want to know how to use external jar files in general..

Comment: Just want to know how to use .jar files in general

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do to configure the PostgreSQL JDBC drivers is clearly documented in sections 2 and 3 of [The PostgreSQL JDBC Interface](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/index.html).

This covers:

- adding the driver JARs to your project,
- modifying your source code to use the driver, and
- creating the "jdbc:" connection URL that tells your Java client code what database to connect to.

If you have a specific question that is not covered by the manual, please update your Question.

Comment: Ok. Working on it. But I see that these are *NIX based settings. Any Windows?

Comment: There's nothing *NIX-based about that information that I can see.  (Apart from setting an environment variable ... and **surely** you know how to do that!)

Answer (score 1):

If you are making web project then here is a project structure:

```
TOMCAT_HOME
    -webapps
        -YourProject
             -WEB_INF
                 -lib
```

Now in lib folder you can have all the jars file used by that project.

By adding files in `TOMCAT_HOME/lib` you make jars available to all projects on that server. I mean all project deployed on that tomcat.